# Detect half width character and full witdth character from a string using c++ (window/linux)

Tags: c++, string

For a given string i want to determine every character is either half-width or full-width.

In windows i can get it done by using

```
BOOL GetStringTypeW(
  [in]  DWORD                         dwInfoType,
  [in]  _In_NLS_string_(cchSrc)LPCWCH lpSrcStr,
  [in]  int                           cchSrc,
  [out] LPWORD                        lpCharType
);
```

then use lpCharType and C3_HALFWIDTH type to determine the char is full-width or half-width.

The problem is i can not use GetStringTypeW in linux platform. I have to either use an GetStringTypeW linux equivalent api or i have to acheive it programmatically.

For start can anyone help me with ideas or a solution.

Thank you.

Comment: There are several unicode libraries available on Linux that provide this information, that's derived from the Unicode database (including one that I wrote). Unfortunately, library recommendations are off-topic on Stackoverflow. www.google.com is your friend.

Comment: [wcwidth](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/wcwidth.3.html)